# Making a list into a list of lists by splitting on an element (and omitting that element)

Tags: haskell, grouping

I have a `data Weather = Sunny | Cloudy | Rainy deriving (Show, Eq)` datatype and my job is to group only the non-rainy days using a `[Weather] -> [[Weather]]` function.

Let's say that I have a list like this:

`[Rainy, Cloudy, Sunny, Sunny, Cloudy, Rainy, Rainy, Sunny, Cloudy, Sunny, Cloudy, Rainy, Sunny]`, and I want to make it into a list of lists containing only the `Sunny` or `Cloudy` days like so:

`[[Cloudy, Sunny, Sunny, Cloudy], [Sunny, Cloudy, Sunny, Cloudy], [Sunny]]`.

I am prohibited to use the `splitOn` function from `Data.List.Split`.

My attempt at solving this:

```
groupNotRainy :: [Weather] -> [[Weather]]
groupNotRainy [] = [[]]
groupNotRainy [x]
   | x /= Rainy = [[x]]
   | otherwise = [[]]
groupNotRainy [x,y]
   | x == Rainy = [[y]]
   | y == Rainy = [[x]]
   | otherwise = [[x,y]]
groupNotRainy (x:y:xs)
   | y == Rainy = [[x], groupNotRainy xs]
```

Which gives me a `Couldn't match type ‘[Weather]’ with ‘Weather’` error.

Comment: Can you show your attempt at solving this and explain what went wrong with it?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Added my non-working solution.

Comment: I think the specific type used here “clouds” your algorithmic problem, so to speak. You could reason with a generic predicate, and go look for some `grouper :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]` function.

Comment: In your last code line, you probably meant `[x] : groupNotRainy xs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close to a solution.
In order to typecheck, the end of your code should be changed like this:

```
groupNotRainy (x:y:xs)
   | y == Rainy  =  [x] : (groupNotRainy xs)
   | otherwise   =  ...TODO...
```

because the type of `groupNotRainy xs` is `[[Weather]]`.

Your following patterns happen to overlap for an empty xs:

```
groupNotRainy [x,y]
groupNotRainy (x:y:xs)
```

so it is probably best to keep just the second one. There, you have 2 boolean values to test. I think the easiest/cleanest (if not shortest) way is just to enumerate the 4 cases:

```
groupNotRainy [] = []
groupNotRainy [x]
   | x /= Rainy  =  [[x]]
   | otherwise   =  []
groupNotRainy (x:y:xs)
   | x == Rainy && y == Rainy         =  groupNotRainy xs
   | x /= Rainy && y == Rainy         =  [x] : (groupNotRainy xs)
   | x == Rainy && y /= Rainy         =  groupNotRainy (y:xs)
   | otherwise  {- both non-rainy -}  =  let  yss = groupNotRainy (y:xs)
                                         in   (x : head yss) : tail yss
```

If both x and y are OK (non-rainy), one computes the result of the function for y:xs, and then prepends x to the first list in that (necessarily non-empty) result.

Please note the last clause is an `otherwise`. The compiler is not omniscient and would complain if it was just `| (p x)  &&  (p y)`.

Besides, it is probably more *idiomatic* to define a general purpose function:

```
grouper :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
grouper p []     = []
grouper p [x]
   | (p x)       =  [[x]]
   | otherwise   =  []
grouper p (x:y:xs)
   | (not $ p x)  &&  (not $ p y)   =  grouper p xs
   | (      p x)  &&  (not $ p y)   =  [x] : (grouper p xs)
   | (not $ p x)  &&  (      p y)   =  grouper p (y:xs)
   | otherwise  {- both x y OK -}   =  let  yss = grouper p (y:xs)  -- not empty
                                       in   (x : head yss) : tail yss
```

and then define `groupNotRainy` by [*currying*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying), also known as “partial application”:

```
groupNotRainy :: [Weather] -> [[Weather]]
groupNotRainy = grouper (/= Rainy)
```